# Conditionally add multiple classes to element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

Suppose I have some `@stuff`, and I'm rendering a table with a few attributes about each `thing`. I want every other row to be colored differently, so I'm using the typical `cycle` trick:

```
%table
  - @stuff.each do |thing|
  %tr{ class: cycle('even', 'odd') }
    %td thing.bleep
    %td thing.bloop
```

But I also want to render certain rows differently based on some conditions related to each particular `thing`. So I want certain rows to *also* have the `foo` class if `thing.foo?` is true. If I weren't doing the `cycle` thing, I'd do:

```
%tr{ class: 'foo' if thing.foo? }
```

Is there a *convenient* way to do *both* of these things? Or do I really have to hand-write the ugly logic to conditionally append these things together with a space inbetween? It just feels like that sort of tedious logic is error-prone, and that there's an an abstraction I should be using to compose these two CSS class alterations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can [use an array for `class` and `id` attributes](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#class-and-id-attributes):

> The `:class` and `:id` attributes can also be specified as a Ruby array whose elements will be joined together. A `:class` array is joined with " " and an `:id` array is joined with "_".

So in this case you could do:

```
%tr{:class => [cycle('even', 'odd'), ('foo' if thing.foo?)]}
```

Any `nil`s are removed from the array so you don’t end up with extra whitespace

Comment: I couldn't get the if syntax to work.  I got it working as follows:  thing.foo? ? 'foo' : ''

Comment: @tolgap You’re right. I’m surprised I added an answer with an error like that–I’m normally pretty good about checking them (and it’s odd no one else pointed it out). I checked back to Ruby 2.0.0 and it fails there too, so it can’t be that Ruby itself changed behaviour since then (unless I was using a really old version at the time). Anyway, a pair of parens seems to fix it.